# Beaming notes which have a rest between them

Tags: beaming

Is it correct to beam two notes with a rest between them? For instance, if you have a quaver followed by a quaver rest, then quaver, will it be correct to beam the two quavers?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good question that may get deleted as it's already been asked and answered here:
[When to use note beaming over/under rests?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/88249/when-to-use-note-beaming-over-under-rests)
One beams across rests when it improves the readibility.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is standard notation as it helps keep groups of beats visually connected.

Here are some examples:

**Bartók String Quartet #5, Allegro, mm. 1-3**

[image: Bartók String Quartet #5, Allegro, mm. 1-3]

**Schumann Op. 68 No. 9, mm. 9-11**

[image: Schumann Op. 68 No. 9, mm. 9-11]